# Changing state on route change Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm toggling navigation in next.js, it works fine, it's just I want the navigation to close again when the route changes.

For example, if I'm on the home page and toggle the navigation, the navigation opens and shows a link to the about page. If I click that link, I get taken to the about page as expected - but the navigation is still open!

I've tried a few things - I think I want to utilize
onRouteChangeComplete(url) but I'm struggling to update the navActive state.

My page.js file:

```
class Page extends Component {
  state = {
    navActive: false
  };

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      navActive: !this.state.navActive
     });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <StyledPage className="full-page-wrapper">
          <Meta />
          <Header navActive={this.state.navActive} toggle={this.toggle} />
          <PrimaryContent>{this.props.children}</PrimaryContent>
          <GlobalStyle />
        </StyledPage>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Then my header file:

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HeaderSide

        <HeaderToggleBar onClick={() => this.props.toggle()} />

      </HeaderSide>
    );
  }
}
```

So the app starts off with navActive state of false, clicking the HeaderToggleBar element opens and closes the nav. But I need to close the nav when the route changes. I guess I could put the click event on the navigation items within the header (so clicking to a new page toggles) but that seems a bit over the top.

Thank you.

Comment: So I have this "working" by applying on onClick event to all links in the nav - so it shuts the nav then navigates to the page. This seems impractical and not very future proof. Also if other links on the page are clicked when the navigation is open, it'll stay open. I just need a solution where the nav closes if the route changes?

Answer (score 49):

if you're using a functional React component, you can do this:

```
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
  if (isMenuOpen) {
    setMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen);
  }
}, [router.asPath]);
```

Comment: The secret is only on the `skipping` argument `, [router.asPath]`.

Comment: Recommend using either `setMenuOpen(state => !state)` or in this case semantically you're probably never interested in opening the menu so to rule out incorrect behaviour in case of a possible flip of the toggle, simply: `setMenuOpen(false)`

Comment: Work for me  ```useEffect(() => {
    closeMenu()
  }, [router.asPath]);```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in the new app/ page structure. It will throw an error and send you to [this page](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted) telling you to migrate to 'next/navigation' hooks.

Answer (score 22):

Have a look at https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#router-events. You should be fine with sth like this in the ctor of your Header component:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', (url) => {
    props.toggle();
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob thanks for that. It doesn't work as I get the error: props is not defined.                        I've put the router event in the Header.js file but not in the constructor as it causes what seems to be an infinite loop and crashes the browser.

Comment: I added the full code for the ctor... should be working.

Answer (score 15):

We can use router events to handle this. Refer: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#usage-6

```
const router = useRouter();
useEffect(() => {
  router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
  return () => {
    router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
  };
}, [router.events]);
```

Answer (score 5):

**Complete example**

Using a functional component.

Triggering on `routeChangeStart`, so the menu can optionally be animated immediately after clicking.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Menu = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const hide = useCallback(() => {
    setShow(false);
  }, [setShow]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // subscribe
    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', hide);
    
    // unsubscribe
    return () => router.events.off('routeChangeStart', hide);
  }, [hide, router.events]);

  return show ? <div>menu</div> : null
}
```

**Managing nesting** (TypeScript)

I needed something like this in top level, though I'd share:

```
interface ContextProps {
  show: boolean;
  setShow: (show: boolean) => void;
};

export const MenuContext = React.createContext<Partial<ContextProps>>({
  show: false,
  setShow: () => {},
});
```

```
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <MenuContext.Provider value={{ show, setShow }}>
      {children}
    </MenuContext.Provider>
  )
```

Comment: this solution is perfect

Answer (score 4):

when route changing is happening, next.js is trying to load the other page. A better way to handle the route change, if you are tracking the loading state, keep that loading state true, until the route change is complete.

```
 const router = useRouter();

 useEffect(() => {
    const handleComplete = () => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleComplete);
    router.events.on("routeChangeError", handleComplete);

    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", handleComplete);
      router.events.off("routeChangeError", handleComplete);
    };
  }, [router]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how we can detect page changes in Next.js 13 App folder.

> You can listen for page changes by composing other Client Component
> hooks like `usePathname` and `useSearchParams`.
>
> ````js
> useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
>
> export function NavigationEvents() {
>     const pathname = usePathname() 
>     const searchParams = useSearchParams()
>     
>     useEffect(() => {
>         const url = `${pathname}?${searchParams}`
>         console.log(url)
>         // You can now use the current URL
>         // ...
>     }, [pathname, searchParams])
>
>     return null } ```
> ````

Link of the doc: [useRouter docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#router-events)

It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

For Nextjs 13 +

```
'use client';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelectedLayoutSegment } from 'next/navigation';

const activeSegment = useSelectedLayoutSegment();


useEffect(() => {
    console.log('>>>>>');
}, [activeSegment]);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router)

There you can see class component base code.
But here I use the functional components to solve this issue.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = () => {
        setOpenDropdown(false)
    }
    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleRouteChange)
}, [])
```

Comment: You must unsubscribe from the event in the clean function of `useEffect`. The event will still be active on other pages if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to bind your callback. You might also need to add a constructor. Here's an snippet from a project that accepts file uploads.

```
    class Files extends React.Component {
        // define your constructor and call super before setting state vars
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                uploadStatus: false
            }
            // Bind your callback
            this.handleUploadImage = this.handleUploadImage.bind(this);
            // set other initial vars if needed
        }

        handleUploadImage(files){
            // do stuff with the files
        }

        render () {
            return (
                <div id="fileContainer">
                    <MyDropzone id={this.props.project._id} onDrop={this.handleUploadImage}>
                        {({getRootProps}) => <div {...getRootProps()} />}
                    </MyDropzone>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```