# running hook inside _app.tsx Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I am having issues with rendering a hook that I use to determine if my components are inside the screens view so that I can animate them. I run this hook in _app.tsx but the function does not run when routing to another page. If I put a console.log() in my _app.tsx it always runs but not mu custom hook.

If I refresh the page my hook runs as it should but I have to manually refresh the page in order for it to actually run and animate my animations.

What I have tried:
Is to run my hook in a  component that I use on all of my pages it works but it takes a split second for it to load and the animations does not run smoothly. When my custom hook is in _app.tsx it does actually run smoothly when I refresh the page manually. That's why I feel like this is the place to have my hook or am I wrong? Maybe this isn't the most optimal way to do this.

The final goal is to have all may animations run smoothly. I want them to run when the component is in View and I want the animations to run again when I navigate to another page.

My _app.tsx looks like this:

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'
import GlobalStyle from '../components/GlobalStyles'
import { useInView } from '../hooks/useInView'
import { theme } from '../theme/theme'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  useInView()
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

My custom hook (useInView()) looks like this:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'

export const useInView = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    function inView() {
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
        (intersections) => {
          intersections.forEach(({ target, isIntersecting }) => {
            if (isIntersecting) {
              target.classList.add('in-view')
            } else {
              target.classList.remove('in-view')
            }
          })
        },
        {
          threshold: 0,
        }
      )

      document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-spy').forEach((element) => {
        observer.observe(element)
      })
    }
    inView()
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing state on route change Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53857063/changing-state-on-route-change-next-js)

Answer (score 0):

When you need to tell a hook to re-render when the path changes, implement a `useEffect` with the pathname as a dependency. Implementation is slightly different depending on if you use `Next.js` or `React`.

**next.js**

Take a look at the [usePathname](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-pathname) hook. Simply applied as such:

`import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';`

Then inside your component you have access to the pathname:

`const pathname = usePathname();`

Then check when it changes before doing something:

```
useEffect(() => {
  inView();
}, [pathname])
```

**react.js**

Take a look at the [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location) hook. It provides the `pathname` property.

`import useLocation from 'react-router-dom'`

Then inside your bring the location in:

`const location = useLocation();`

Then check when it changes before doing something:

```
useEffect(() => {
  inView();
}, [location.pathname])
```

You'll need to slightly re-adjust where you define your `inView()` function but this is essentially how you do something when the view changes.

I also created a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-18-2-detect-visible-screen-element-10e7cr) that demonstrates `IntersectionObserver` observer and how to implement it using React  components in case you're struggling with that. It shows an alert when the green box's visibility changes.

Comment: The OP incorrectly tagged their question with `react-router` while they're actually using NextJS.

Comment: Added the `next.js` instructions, thank you.

Comment: I think you are still misunderstanding the post and @code's comment. It doesn't appear that routes or any URL path or location have anything at all to do with the scroll container, the IntersectionObserver, or the React hook the OP says they are having a problem getting to run.

Comment: `I run this hook in _app.tsx but the function does not run when routing to another page.`