# Next.js 13 router methods do not exist. How to cause a state change when routing

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next-router

Methods that previously existed in next/router don't seem to work with next 13 (latest).
I get a mounting issue if I use anything from next/router, so it's suggested to use next/navigation per docs.

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted

next/navigation does not have all the functionality next router did, even when i alias next/router, i still cant use any of it per the mounting issue.

I'm just trying to close a component that renders a div when I navigate to another page within the app, but listeners or history or events.on/events.off don't seem to work.

I've set the state to false in various places, all it is is a show/hide boolean, but i cant hide when navigating.

another example of a method that doesnt exist in next/navigation.

```
useRouter().onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  handleRouteChange();
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a similar issue, but this is dated and doesnt work with latest next as I cannot use next/router ? [Changing state on route change Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53857063/changing-state-on-route-change-next-js/77446340#77446340)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router from `next/router` is not initialized inside the `app` directory as you have already correctly noticed yourself.

```
"use client";

import { useEffect } from "react";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

interface Props {
  onChange: (pathname: string) => void;
}

export default function PathTracker({ onChange }: Props) {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  useEffect(() => onChange(pathname), [pathname]);
  return <></>;
}
```

As seen in the example I have provided above, you can use the `usePathname` hook to determine any change in the current path.

Comment: This worked. Thank you!